# DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting throwing error with reporting enabled false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, dotnetopenauth, isolatedstorage

I just added DotNetOpenAuth into an MVC project which runs perfectly fine on my localhost but when I deploy to the hosting environment I am getting a reporting error to do with isolated storage.

I followed the previous advice of disabling the reporting if it is causing a problem but that does not appear to solve the issue.

I understand that it is failing since it cannot write to the isolated storage on my shared hosting environment.

So questions :

Why is the reporting still throwing an error when it is disabled?

Is there a way to set the isolated storage to use a custom folder which the site is able to access so that I can leave the reporting on?

Thanks

My Web.config section:

```
    <dotNetOpenAuth>
      <reporting enabled="false" />
    <!-- Relaxing SSL requirements is useful for simple samples, but NOT a good idea in production. -->
    <messaging relaxSslRequirements="true">
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
        <add name="localhost" />
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->

    <!-- This is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized. -->
    <!-- For a complete set of configuration options see http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/configuration-options/ -->
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
      <provider></provider>
    </openid>
   </dotNetOpenAuth>
```

Added the section Group Section:

```
<sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
    <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Error Log:

```
2015-07-24 12:52:58,249 [1] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth [(null)] - DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.4.12333, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246 (official)
2015-07-24 12:52:58,342 [1] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth [(null)] - Reporting will use isolated storage with scope: Domain, Assembly, Machine
2015-07-24 12:52:58,374 [1] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth [(null)] - Error while trying to initialize reporting.
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Unable to create mutex. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131464)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Open(String infoFile, String syncName)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.Lock(Boolean& locked)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.GetOrCreateOriginIdentity()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.Initialize()
```

Comment: Your web.config snippet doesn't include a required part: the configSections tag that defines where the DotNetOpenAuth section is defined. Have you got that part too?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the config section, Thanks